# Correct structure for micro services - Subscription based model

Tags: microservices

I have user service, course service and subscription service, email service.
How should they interact with each other for following:

1. User subscribing to a course(User selects a course) (Single/multiple courses)
2. Adding users to a course(We click on a course and users to it) (Single/multiple users)
3. Email is sent on subscription, which talk to user and course service for details

I know it's an abstract question, but it would be great help if you guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, if you have two related services and both of them need partial information of the other (case of users and courses), for performance reasons you should store information of the other service.

I mean, in users you should store information of the course subscribed by each user (normally the id or/and the name) and in courses the information about the users subscribed in each.

The way to keep the information properly synchronized, could be using a message broker like kafka where each service will post every modification and the other service will consume it.

For example when a user quits from a course the users service will publish a message notifying the courses and then this will update properly and vice versa.

The problem with this approach is the eventual consistency, perhaps an better solution could be to have a suscription service where the logic of suscription is centralized and then only specific information of users and courses in its respective service.

In case of the notification service, I think the best approach is the service to be listen on other topic from the message broker and the other service will publish there a command to send the email when a suscription is made.